# Want to display Addition result in textbox.? here is my code

Tags: java, jsp

addition.jsp

```html
<form action="addition.jsp">
  First Number
  <input type="text" name="fno">
  <br>
  <br>Second Number
  <input type="text" name="sno">
  <br>
  <br>Result
  <input type="text" value="<%=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(" fno "))+Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sno ")) %>">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ADD">
</form>
```

I want to display result in thrid textbox named Result on click of submit button.. i tried this code but getting error ..is there something am i missing..kindly help?

Comment: You won't have a result until the form submits (so you can't access the request parameters on the first request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.getParameter(" fno ") is string  not a number therefore it will be a wrong format.

```
<%
String integer = request.getParameter("fno");     
String integer1 = request.getParameter("sno"); 
int x = integer != null ? Integer.parseInt(integer) : 0;      
int y = integer1 != null ? Integer.parseInt(integer1) : 0;
int z=x+y;
 %>
 <input type="text" name="integer" value="<%=z%>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by simple java script as follow:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="addition.jsp">
  First Number
  <input type="text" name="fno" id="fno"/>
  <br>
  <br>Second Number
  <input type="text" name="sno" id="sno"/>
  <br>
  <br>Result
  <input type="text"  id="result"/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="setAddition();"/>
</form>
<script>
function setAddition()
{
var fno=document.getElementById("fno").value;
var sno=document.getElementById("sno").value;
document.getElementById("result").value=parseInt(fno)+parseInt(sno);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya that i know from javascript to display addition result but i wanted to display the result using jsp..Thanks